# Nuke viewer LUT settings while working on alpha channel

Tags: python, alpha, color-space, nuke

As per my knowledge, LUT is meant to be applied on color channels (RGB) since we are doing colorspace conversion. But Nuke's viewer LUT settings affect alpha channel too. I am aware that viewer LUT doesn't alter original pixel values but only displays them as per the LUT settings set, but shouldn't we turn off viewer LUT while working on alpha channel? Like for instance pulling a key or doing roto ?

Shouldn't we be viewing alpha in linear color space? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, NUKE Viewer's LookUp Table doesn't change alpha at all but it affects it. You need to use Viewer's `f/8` (multiplier) slider and `y` (gamma) slider for changing appearance of your alpha when you're keying. NUKE's **working** color space is **LINEAR** but **default** LUT settings for `monitor`, `8-bit` and `16-bit` files are **superRGB** corrected:

[image]

Read an article about NUKE colorspaces and **color transformations**: [HERE](https://support.foundry.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000229764-Q100319-How-to-use-colorspaces-in-Nuke-).

To compensate sRGB gamma for getting linear working color space NUKE uses mirrored gamma:

[image]

You can change any default LUT settings or turn off alpha channel (or rgb, or any channel you want) for your convenience at any time.

Execute this code and then create new Viewer node with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> shortcut (<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> on a Mac):

```
import nuke

# to change Viewers' properties globally
nuke.knobDefault('Viewer.channels', 'rgb')
nuke.knobDefault('Viewer.viewerProcess', 'rec709')  # use rec709, for instance
```

You'll get this:

[image]

Or simply execute the code for Viewer1, changing `viewerProcess` for `None` (linear color space):

```
nuke.toNode('Viewer1').knob('channels').setValue('alpha')
nuke.toNode('Viewer1').knob('viewerProcess').setValue('None')

# then add these 3 lines to menu.py file (they'll work after restart)

nuke.knobDefault("Root.monitorLut", "linear")  # monitor LUT
nuke.knobDefault("Root.int8Lut", "linear")     # 8-bit files LUT
nuke.knobDefault("Root.int16Lut", "linear")    # 16-bit files LUT
```

[image]

[image]

Additionally, to physically transform you current LUT, you can use `OpenColorIO LUT` and `3D LUT` nodes from `Color` Toolbar's menu.

**And a few words about Pixel Analyzer panel:**

`Current`, `Min`, `Max`, `Average` and `Median` operations in Pixel Analyzer panel are applied to any channels from dropdown menu. If you need only alpha value or only `rgb` values just choose it from the menu.

[image]

But. There's no mistake if you'll be using rgba mode. Check it. Apply Keyer node to the image and you'll see RGB values are the same with or without alpha (but only if rgba isn't premultiplied).

***And it's sad but there still isn't access to API via Python for the Pixel Analyzer panel***.

Comment: "You need to use Viewer's f/8 (multiplier) slider and y (gamma) slider for changing appearance of your alpha when you're keying." Isn't setting viewer LUT to none easier than this?

Comment: My question was not about how to setup viewer LUT but why we are not working in linear color space while working on alpha channel.  Still the answer was informative. Upvoted :)

Comment: our working color space is Linear (it's corrected). https://support.foundry.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000229764-Q100319-How-to-use-colorspaces-in-Nuke-

Comment: "Isn't setting viewer LUT to "None" easier than this?"  Nope. The f/8 (multiplier) slider and y (gamma) slider made specially for keying and color correcting issues. Transforming your Viewer color space into "None" is unnecessary.

Comment: We are working in Linear color space in NUKE !!! The legacy sRGB color space is from eighties and nineties...

Comment: You have Displayed-On-Monitor-Gamma and Corrected-Gamma what results in Linear Color Space in NUKE.

Comment: By working in linear color space, I meant working without any viewer LUT applied.

Comment: I just wanted to clear why viewer LUT is applied to alpha when its only meant to be applied to rgb channels.

Comment: there are "rgb" pattern and "rgba". Use RGB when you do not need A and use just A or RGBA when you need it.

Comment: "By working in linear color space, I meant working without any viewer LUT applied". It's a legacy issue. Apple Shake, for example, uses Linear color space from scratch. But NUKE is via LUT.

Comment: It's not only for NUKE users)) For Photoshop users too: To prepare your images for consistent display quality you’ll need to convert files to the sRGB color profile. sRGB is the color profile used by most web browsers to display images on the web.

Comment: This is because NUKE and other software rely on the Grassman's Law principle of additive colour mixture. More information about it can be found here: https://www5.in.tum.de/lehre/vorlesungen/graphik/info/csc/COL_11.htm